# When, if ever, is someone in the seaside shack?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

[image]

Does this message ever change? Do I need to come at a certain time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's been a recent revamp to the Sea that I'm unaware of, the Seaside Shack is not accessible until level 11. I would suggest, however, that you not do any of the Sea content until level 15-ish as the monsters are very high-level and can hit pretty hard.